# Does anyone know how to display one field condition in php

Tags: php, html

I have a situation where I need to compare 3 different select option fields of the same table. I compared 3 fields, 2 fields and 1 field. The corresponding  results are displayed, but in one field condition (`category`) result are not displayed.

```
<?php
    include'connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $qn=$_POST['location'];//LOCATION
        $qn1=$_POST['category'];//CATEGORY
        $qn2=$_POST['salary'];//SALARY

        if(isset($_POST['location']))
        {
            $q2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting where location='$qn'");
            while($quew=mysql_fetch_array($q2))
            {  
                echo $ans=$quew['title'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $qir=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting where category='$qn1'"); 
            while($quew=mysql_fetch_array($qir))
            {  
                echo $gn=$quew['title'];
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['category']))
        {
            $q3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting where location='$qn' && category='$qn1'");
            while($quew=mysql_fetch_array($q3))
            {  
                echo $ans2=$quew['title'];
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['salary']))
        {
            $q4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting where location='$qn'  && category='$qn1' && minsalary='$qn2'"); 
             while($quew=mysql_fetch_array($q4))
            {  
                echo $ans3=$quew['title'];
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['location']) || isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['salary']))
        {
            $q5=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting where location='$qn'  || category='$qn1' && minsalary='$qn2'"); 
            while($quew=mysql_fetch_array($q5))
            {  
                echo $ans4=$quew['title'];
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['category']) || isset($_POST['salary']))
        {
            $q7=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting where location='$qn'  && category='$qn1' || minsalary='$qn2'"); 
            while($quew=mysql_fetch_array($q7))
            {  
                echo $ans5=$quew['title'];
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the deprecated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I can think of three things

- Database Query => check if request the "category"
- Database Type => utf8-bin, utf8-general-ci etc.. because is very important how are saved data.
- Server file "php.ini" => check "default_charset" and "mbstring..." params, is important to manage string type data.

If you need more help only need send we more information

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['location'])) {
    $lq = "&& location='$_POST['location']'";
}

if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
    $cq = "&& category='$_POST[category]'";
}

if (!empty($_POST['salary'])) {
    $sq = "&& minsalary='$_POST[salary]'";
}

$qr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting WHERE 1 $lq $cq $sq");
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```